# Wired issue with dynamically adding checkboxes to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code:

```js
const boxes = ["we", "the people of Earth", "I'm", "they're"];
/* Checkbox scripts */
const boxsContainer = document.querySelector('.boxs-container');

const checkboxes = boxes.map( box => {
    
  const divBoxes = document.createElement('div');
  divBoxes.classList.add('container-checkbox');
  divBoxes.innerHTML = `
    <input class="checkmark" onclick='copyText("${box}")' type="checkbox" name="${box}">
    <label id="${box}" for="${box}">&nbsp;&nbsp;${box}</label>
  `;
  boxsContainer.appendChild(divBoxes);
  return divBoxes.querySelector('input'); 
    
});

function copyText(text) {
    console.log(text);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxs-container"></div>
```

As you see I want to dynamically add the `boxes` elements into the DOM with a checkbox and when you check each one you get the log of the `box` which has been checked.

But the issue is I get errors if I have a text with apostrophe sign `'`...

click on I'm or they're and you get an error...

And here is the elements tab with these wired result!!!

[image: wired]

How to fix this?

Comment: That's because you are delimiting the attribute value with single quotes: `onclick='copyText("${box}")'`. As HTML this will look like `onclick='copyText("they're")'`, so the value of the `onclick` attribute ends at the second `'`. It would be better to use the DOM API to create those elements (`document.createElement`) and assign the event handler with `onclick` or `addEventListener`.

Comment: I can't do that on my own would you please provide an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Felix you need to use addEventListener. This code will help.

```
const boxes = ["we", "the people of Earth", "I'm", "they're"];
/* Checkbox scripts */
const boxsContainer = document.querySelector('.boxs-container');

const checkboxes = boxes.map( box => {
    
  const divBoxes = document.createElement('div');
  divBoxes.classList.add('container-checkbox');
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  input.setAttribute("name", `${box}`);
  input.addEventListener('click', copyText.bind(null,`${box}`));
  divBoxes.appendChild(input);
  
  var x = document.createElement("label");
  x.setAttribute('for', `${box}`)
  x.setAttribute('id', `${box}`)
  x.innerHTML = `${box}`
  divBoxes.appendChild(x);
  

  /*divBoxes.innerHTML = `
    <input class="checkmark" onclick='copyText("${box}")' type="checkbox" name="${box}">
    <label id="${box}" for="${box}">&nbsp;&nbsp;${box}</label>
  `;*/
  
  boxsContainer.appendChild(divBoxes);
  return divBoxes.querySelector('input'); 
    
});

function copyText(e, text) {
    console.log(e);
}
```